# WordPress, Elementor Pro, Post - custom query not working

Tags: wordpress, post, elementor

I'm really stuck on this. Trying to add (any) basic custom query to an Elementor Post widget.

Issue - custom query is just ignored, widget displays all posts, regardless of custom query params.

Config

- WP 6.0.2
- Elementor Pro 3.7.7 (I'm using containers)
- WPCode - 2.0.2

screenshot of widget config: https://imtanuki.tinytake.com/msc/NzM5ODAwMF8yMDI4MDg2Ng

code snippet

```
function custom_query_test_02 ( $query ) {
$query_args = array(
        'post_status' => 'draft',
    );
    
    $query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
    return $query;
}

add_action( 'elementor/query/{$query_id}', 'custom_query_test_02' );
```

I've tried:

- adding code to functions
- different filters
- various syntax for setting $query

Nothing works! No errors thrown, but it just ignores the custom query.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation suggests that {$query_id} in the following line is interpolated, similar to templating languages.

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/{$query_id}', 'custom_query_test_02' );
```

I discovered that a literal is needed to make this work:

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/xxxxxx', 'custom_query_test_02' );
```

Using a literal seems to work fine...